# Create a background transition in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a row with two blocks inside in which a background image opens in the row when a picture is passed on.

Unfortunately I can not change the html code much while I can change it with css.

So when I go to the internal image, the hover class is added to the line.

I would like the background to somehow have a transition.
For now it only takes one shot and I can not change it.

this is my css:

```css
#rowContattaci {
    background: black;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 30% !important;
    transition: 1s;
    min-height:100px;
    margin-left: 0% !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}

#rowContattaci.hover {
    background: url("https://onaliternote.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/wp-1480230666843.jpg?crop");
    transition: 2s !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="rowContattaci" data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid eightRow sectionContattaci rowHome section" style="position: relative; left: -231.094px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1920px; padding-left: 231.094px; padding-right: 242.906px;"></div>
```

Comment: Why all the important. usually it means bad CSS

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo. Useful ref: [CSS :hover Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Anyway change `#rowContattaci.hover` to `#rowContattaci:hover` to resolve your issue.

Update Snippet:

```css
#rowContattaci {
    background: black;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 30% !important;
    transition: 1s;
    min-height:100px;
    margin-left: 0% !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}

#rowContattaci:hover {
    background: url("https://onaliternote.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/wp-1480230666843.jpg?crop");
    transition: 2s !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="rowContattaci" data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid eightRow sectionContattaci rowHome section" style="position: relative; left: -231.094px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1920px; padding-left: 231.094px; padding-right: 242.906px;"></div>
```

P.S. My suggestions:

1) Keep all your styles together i.e. to not keep half of your styles inline and half external.

2) Avoid using !important everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you need to change to get your example to work:

1. As others have mentioned, there's a typo with your css hover style - it should be `:hover` not `.hover`
2. You need to apply some **positioning and sizing on your background image** otherwise, you only see the top left of the image, which also happens to be black, so it looks like it just flashes but does not show the logo.

**Tips**: I would also second thebrownkid's recommendation that you separate your css styles rather than writing in-line css. The example below removes all the unnecessary styles.

```css
#rowContattaci {
  background-color: black;
  padding-right: 30%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#rowContattaci:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("https://onaliternote.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/wp-1480230666843.jpg?crop");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="rowContattaci"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't make your background picture blend in a transition. However you could use a trick with 2 `div`s one on top of the other. The bottom one will always have a background image, the top one will change color from `transparent` to `black` in transition.

All you have to do is to align the elements properly.

```css
#rowContattaci {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: none;
    transition: 1s;
    min-height:100px;
    margin-left: 0% !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    margin: 0;
}

#rowContattaci:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

#rowContattaciBack {
    background-image: url("https://onaliternote.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/wp-1480230666843.jpg?crop");
    background-size: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rowContattaciBack" style="position: relative; left: -231.094px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1920px; padding-left: 231.094px; padding-right: 242.906px; margin:0;">
  <div id="rowContattaci" data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid eightRow sectionContattaci rowHome section">
  </div>
</div>
```